# Is there a way to implement ajax search with dojo data grid component?

Tags: dojo

I am using dojox.grid.DataGrid and dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore to render a grid. I want to implement a record search. Is there any way to do this?

After loading the page someone can search through the 'search form' above the grid. when the search button is pressed it will refresh/reload the grid data returned from the server according to the form values.

Please check the illustration.
[image: The overall system will look like this or whatever is better]

Comment: Can you give some more details pls? When do you need to make the search? After reading the store? Or after one item is added or modified? In the first case you can make your search just before loading the store into the grid, and in the second case you can define a listener

Comment: Please solve me this. How can I reload the grid store-data through ajax according to the form values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply the filter() method on the DataGrid instance. Here you'll find the exact answer to your problem: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/grid/DataGrid.html#filtering-data